# Are my assumptions correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove $\aleph_{0} $<c

Here is full hint:
To do this show $2^{\aleph_{0}}$=c
(i.e the number of real numbers is the same as
the number of subsets of positive integers)  by making a decimal out of each subset of Z+. It is easier if you first observe that
|R|=|(0,1)|=|{0,1} $\cup${0}|,which can be done geometrically by
the following pic:[image]
Where we have bent the interval of (0,1) into a semicircle and
place it tangent to R with .5 on (0,1)touching 0 to R Then show |(0,1)|=|P(Z+)| by making decimals out of the subsets of Z+, and subset s of Z+

My assumption is to do a similar proof that R is uncountable for |(0,1)| and go from there

If this is true,I have a good idea how to do it

Other things I know

Let X={1,2,...n} then P(X)=$2^{n}$
hence |P(X)|=c

|X|=$ \aleph_{0}$.

Comment: "similar proof that $\Bbb R$ is uncountable" -- but that is *literally* what $\aleph_0<\mathfrak c$ expresss

Comment: @AlvinLepik This says nothing about $\aleph_1$;  $\mathfrak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}$  The continuum hypothesis is $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: @AlvinLepik Where do you see $\aleph_1$ enter the game?

Comment: I think he probably means a binary fraction rather than a decimal fraction, although I've heard some people call the "binary decimals" which seems to me a contradiction in terms.  Anyway, note that finite sets and co-finite sets get mapped to the same numbers, so you have to deal with this.

Comment: I didn’t state $\aleph_1$. It was in the book. @saulspatz

Comment: @Plotinus I was responding to AlvinLepik's comment, as you'll see if you look at it.  Since you are the post author, you get pinged with every comment, but not every one of them is directed to you.  Some are discussions among the commenters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Observation.** If $X$ is any set and $f\colon X\to 2^X$ is any map, then$f$ is not onto.

*Proof.* Given $X$ and $f$, define $A:=\{\,x\in X\mid x\notin f(x)\,\}$. Assume $f(a)=A$ for some $a\in X$. If $a\notin A\iff a\notin f(a)\iff a\in A$, contradiction. $\square$

**Observation.** The map $g\colon 2^{\Bbb N}\to\Bbb R$, $A\mapsto \sum_{n\in A}3^{-n}$ is injective.

*Proof.* Assume $A,B$ are distintc subsets of $\Bbb N$ and let $N=\min(A\mathop \Delta B)$.
Wlog $N\in A$ and $N\notin B$. Then
$$ g(A)\ge \sum_{n\in A\atop n<N}3^{-n}+3^{-N}>\sum_{n\in A\atop n<N}3^{-n}+\frac12\cdot 3^{-N}=\sum_{n\in A\atop n<N}3^{-n}+\sum_{n>N}3^{-n}=\sum_{n\in B\atop n<N}3^{-n}+\sum_{n>N}3^{-n}\ge g(B)$$
$\square$

Conclude that
$$ \aleph_0=|\Bbb N|<|2^{\Bbb N}|\le|\Bbb R|=\mathfrak c.$$

Comment: This is a nice proof I was thinking of a Cantor’s diagonalisation technique on (0,1) or [0,1]@HagenvonEitzen